# PHP Facebook API issue with business page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app which posts news from a company website to the company's Facebook business page.

When I test it with my developer account's id or my private account id, it works great. But when I use the id of the business page, no news show up on the chronic.

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'library/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
));


if(is_null($facebook->getUser())){
    header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' =>    'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,offline_access,publish_checkins'))}");
    exit;
}

if($facebookpost){
    try {
      $facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);   
      $img = $sitepath.$gfxpath.$filename;

      $arguments = array(
        'source' => '@' . $img,
        'message' => utf8_encode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($text))),

      );

      $facebook->api("/".FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID."/photos", 'post', $arguments);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      print $e;
    }
}
?>
```

The app shows up correctly in the profile setting (image)
[image: app permissions]

are there some different settings for business pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting Photo to facebook fan page via iOS app by regular non-admin users](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10912901/posting-photo-to-facebook-fan-page-via-ios-app-by-regular-non-admin-users)

Comment: (i know this isn't an iOS question, but the API works the same way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the page's access token to post updates to your page. You can get the access token for the page by calling the following API endpoint:
`/me/accounts`, then look for your page ID / Name.

Comment: i found the access token. but how do i use it?

Comment: thank you. this was the solution!  actually i had to set the permission "manage_page" in the app to get a list of all pages managed by that user. for every page there is an acces_token which is used to post sucessfully on a facebook page